# Sorting and Filtering React - Context

Tags: reactjs

I did a little bit of research but I found old examples with usually Redux or with one main component and cannot figure out the logic.

I can get data from an API but I do need to search, sort, filter, etc on that data (even at the same time). I know that I should not mutate the state directly, so in this case, I will have a couple of different state sets such as filteredData, sortedData, etc. However, which state am I going to pass to the Player component? How will sorting functionality will work on filtered data? I am extremely confused.

I would like to put my state and state-related logic in a Context but if this seems problematic or wrong, then I can try your approach.

**Context**

```
const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('URL HERE')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data=> setData(data));
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    const filteredData = data.filter(player=>
        player.name.includes(value)
    );
    setFilteredData(filteredData);
  };

  const handleSort = e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    // I am trying to sort FILTERED DATA?
    const sortedData = filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[value] < b[value]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    });
    setSortedData(sortedData);
  };

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{ data, handleSearch, handleSort, filteredData, sortedData}}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Search**

```
const Search = () => {

  const { handleSearch, handleSort } = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <div className='row'>
      <Input
        type='search'
        name='search'
        onChange={handleSearch}
      ></Input>
      <Input
        type='select'
        name='select'
        onChange={handleSort}
      >
        <option value='name'>Name</option>
        <option value='team'>Team</option>
      </Input>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Player**

```
const Player = () => {
  const {data, filteredData, sortedData} = useContext(Context);
  return (
      <ul>
        //{data or filteredData or sortedData will be mapped?}
        <li>// not sure what to do</li>
      </ul>
  );
};
```

I really appreciate code examples with some explanation.

Comment: or you could just introduce a new state which by default gonna have the data, `const [finalData, setFInalData] = useState(data)`. And if you got `sortedData` or `filteredData` wanna display afterwards, just update the `setFinalData(toWhatDataSetYouWant)`

Comment: Update: I am waiting for a simple solution without using Context API at all.

Comment: I just made a working [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2gybnj?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHome.js). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this.

My suggestion would be:-

1. Set `const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(data)` **(this will not work)**. So do `useEffect()` to update `filteredData` in `Player` then:-

```
useEffect(() => {
  setFilteredData(data)
}, [])
```

2. On every request (inputs) made by user will be updated by `setFilteredData()`

- if user do nothing with the `inputs`, then return `filteredData` which contain dafault `data`
- if user do `search` input, then do `filtering` search on `filteredData` (using `setFilteredData()`)
- if user do `sort` input, then do `sorting` on `filteredData` (using `setFilteredData()`)
- if user do both `search` and `sort` inputs, then do both action on `filteredData` (using `setFilteredData()`)

3. in `Player`, you can just `return` `filteredData`

#### Context

```
const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [searchKey, setSearchKey] = useState('');
  const [sortKey, setSortKey] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('URL HERE')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data=> setData(data));
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = () => {
    const filteredData = filteredData.filter(player=>
        player.name.includes(searchKey)
    );
    setFilteredData(filteredData);
  };

  const handleSort = () => {
    const sortedData = filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    });
    setFilteredData(sortedData);
  };

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        data, filteredData, searchKey, sortKey,
        setFilteredData, setSearchKey, setSortKey,
        handleSearch, 
        handleSort, 
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

#### Search

```
const Search = () => {

  const {
    searchKey, setSearchKey,
    sortKey, setSortKey
  } = useContext(Context);
  
  return (
    <div className='row'>
      <Input
        type='search'
        name='search'
        value={searchKey}
        onChange={e => setSearchKey(e.target.value)}
      ></Input>
      <Input
        type='select'
        name='select'
        value={sortKey}
        onChange={e => setSortKey(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value='name'>Name</option>
        <option value='team'>Team</option>
      </Input>
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Player

```
const Player = () => {
  const {
    data,
    filteredData, setFilteredData,
    searchKey, sortKey.
    handleSearch, handleSort
  } = useContext(Context);
 
  // set filteredData
  useEffect(() => {
    setFIlteredData(data)
  }, []) // should run once on mounted

  // do search
  // should be dependent on search input state (so you need a state to hold value need for searching)
  useEffect(() => {
    handleSearch()
  }, [searchKey]) // will only fired/run if searchState changes

  // do sorting
  // should be dependent on sorting input state (so you need a state to hold value need for sorting)
  useEffect(() => {
    handleSort()
  }, [sortKey]) // will only fired/run if sortingState changes

  return (
      <ul>
        {filteredData.map(data => (
          {/* display data info */}
        ))}
      </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: First of all, `filteredData` returns an empty array after the component is mounted. If I do search for something first, then I will be able to see players on the screen Also, sorting logic seems not working in this approach.

Comment: I already update my answer above. By the way, handling **searching** and **sorting** should be more accurate and makes sense if you handle it using `useEffect` instead of just directly do it by calling function `handleSearch` or `handleSort`

Comment: You can see **above** example to get an idea of how to make this work

Comment: You are calling `setFilteredData` without referencing it from then Context. Even if you reference it, this is not going to work.

Comment: It does not work. Still, there are problems with searching and sorting. Let's forget sorting. This logic somehow does not filter anything, it does always render the original state. I don't know why this simple thing became very problematic and complicated.

Comment: my bad. In `Player` previously I did `useEffect(() => {setFilteredData(data)})`. It runs non-stop like that. Try adding second `argument` of **empty** `array` to allow it to run **once**, like so `useEffect(() => {setFilteredData(data)}, [])`

Comment: Nope. I am pretty sure we are violating very fundamental rules in React. Even eslint warns me about dependencies basically saying "useless and missing". Anyway, I will wait someone else's approach anymore. Thank you.

Comment: if you could provide a sample sandbox that would be great.